# SF Community-built-with-Templates integration with Google Tag Manager

Tags: community, napili, lightning-community

To integrate SF Community with Google Tag Manager, GTM provides two code snippets to be installed into 'head' and 'body' tag of the Community site.
SF Community allows to install code-snippet into 'head' tag,
but How to install second code-snippet into 'body' tag of the Community (for example if Napili Template is used) ?